# Decrease percentage of the price variable - OpenCart

Tags: php, formula, opencart, percentage, opencart-3

I am interested in one aspect,
I want to show price on OpenCart product page with -11.76470588% from final price.
Or:
I need to display two type of prices.

So is there a way? Variable: {{ price }}
Or something like this: 1 - ({{ price }} / 1.19 * 1.05) / X

Thank you!

My code:

```
    {% if category_id=='69' %}
                    
                        <div class="pret-cu-tva5">Preț cu TVA 5&#37;:   {% if price %}
                {#========= Product - Price ========= #}
                <div class="product_page_price price" itemprop="offerDetails" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Offer">
                    {% if not special %}
                        <span class="price-new"><span itemprop="price" id="price-old">{{ price }}</span></span>
                    {% else %}
                        <span class="price-new"><span itemprop="price" id="price-special">{{ special }}</span></span>
                       <span class="price-old" id="price-old">{{ price }}</span>
                    {% endif %}
                    
                    {% if special and soconfig.get_settings('listing_discount_status')   %} 
                    {#=======Discount Label======= #}
                    <span class="label-product label-sale">
                         {{ discount }}
                    </span>
                    {% endif %} 

                    {% if tax %}
                        <div class="price-tax"><span>{{ text_tax }}</span> <span id="price-tax"> {{ tax }} </span></div>
                    {% endif %}
                 
                </div>
                
                
            
                
                
                {% endif %}
                    

                {% if discounts %} 
                    <ul class="list-unstyled text-success">
                    {% for discount in discounts %} 
                        <li><strong>{{ discount.quantity }} {{ text_discount }} {{ discount.price }}</strong> </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}  </div>
```

No results, tried $percent = (($rowx->Orgprice - $rowx->SalePrice)*100) /$rowx->Orgprice ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the PHP template that Opencart uses,
{{ price }} is the expression. Everything must be within the {{ }} for the calculation.
So, apply the adjustments as such:

{{ price * .88235 }} or
{{ 1 - (price/ 1.19 * 1.05) }}/X

in your very specific case.

Comment: Woaw, very nice. Thank you, I have put this and it gives me the value I wanted {{ price/ 1.19 * 1.05 }} but it have now lot's of decimals. There is a code I can use to reveal only 2?

Comment: You can use round(), as in {{ round(1 - (price/ 1.19 * 1.05), 2)}}/X

Comment: Please mark as a correct answer if you so believe.  Thanks.

Comment: Well I get this error Unknown "round" function, but I will try more. I think OpenCart don't allow () - and I actually need 3 decimals x.yyy but anyways you point me in the good direction, to resolve multiple OpenCart resolutions, so thank you very much!

Comment: That's odd.  There's also number_format().

Comment: {{ round(price/ 1.19 * 1.05),3 }} tried this also but I don't think it's good. I will try with number_format. Thanks!

Comment: Dirty fix until I find the solution, limited the number by css

.pret-cu-tva5-pret-numar {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 4em;
}